Herstein notation
In Herstein's Topic in Algebra he writes

Let $F$ be a finite field having $q$ elements (if you wish, think of $J_p$ with its $p$ elements). Viewing $F$ merely as a group under addition, since $F$ has $q$ elements, by Corollary 2 to Theorem 2.4.1, $$ \underbrace{a + a + \dots + a}_{q \text{-times}} 
= qa = 0.$$

But he also writes

For simplicity of notation we shall henceforth drop the dot in $a \cdot b$ and merely write this product as $ab$.

But $q$ is not necessarily element of field $F$, so how does $qa = 0$ come?

This is defined earlier. In an abelian group, with an element $a$, for positive $n$, $na$ means "adding $a$ to itself $n$ times". It is the additive equivalent of writing $a^n$ when your operation is multiplication.

Sorry but could you point to the relevant page

My edition is in Spanish. The meaning is literally in the quote you give. $qa$ is shorthand for "add $a$ to itself $q$ times."

See the dupe on "abusive" notation for $n$'th multiples and powers. $\ \ $
